# Need help with a Slide JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, slider

I need to animate slides from left to right or right to left (depending upon which slide is selected). I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/b25dR/) set up with a JavaScript that I'm trying to get to work. Currently, it displays the last slide upon page load and scrolls top to bottom.

Can someone show me how to make it so it will display the first slide, then move the slides left to right and right to left when clicking the various links.

Please note: it has to be plain vanilla JavaScript -- no jQuery!

http://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/b25dR/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can we use css transforms ? On what browsers must it work ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no CSS transforms AND it must work all the way down to the dreaded IE6. :(

Comment: You're asking for pain if you want it to work on IE6 and not use a javascript library.

Comment: That's a lot less funny (and smooth) without the css transforms  ;)

Comment: Out of interest, why no jQuery? I'm seeing that a lot recently – seems slightly odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:  http://jsfiddle.net/b25dR/18/

This even works in IE6.